# Form processing in ASP

Tags: forms, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a form on my webpage (it is an asp file). Is it best practice to include the form authentication scripts (in this case username and password check) in the same file or to have it separately? My thought process is that this will happen:

- user enters data in form
- on submit data is sent to the 'authentication' asp page where script processes input
- script checks against data in file
- script page then redirects back to original page with 'login successful' or 'unsuccessful' message.

Is this along the right lines?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd separate them out. I find it convenient to have the authentication logic in one place, separate from other stuff, although there are many other ways to accomplish this than placing the authentication on another page. One more concrete advantage is that you could have several login forms on different pages that all submit to the authentication script, which then could redirect the user back whence they came. This may or may not be any use to you, and you could always refactor it to this approach later if you found you needed it.

Comment: Thanks thats a big help....its good to check if my thinking is on the right lines sometimes!!!

Comment: sorry another basic question...once it has been authenticated by the external script, will it load back to the original form page?!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path. Yes, it would make sense to authenticate on a separate page. From my experience, it makes the single-page approach much more spaghetti-like. I've seen the single-page approach done before, and it just gets hairy.

Other things to consider may to also put useful logic in another file to be used as an INCLUDE file within the authentication handler page. Just a thought to get some code reuse.

Comment: sorry another basic question...once it has been authenticated by the external script, will it load back to the original form page?!

Comment: Depends on the intent of the application. Not sure what your needs are. Your form could be a login page, in which, the authentication page directs the user to the person's profile page. Your application could be a login page in shopping cart on a product page, in which, upon successful authentication, you are redirected to the shopping cart page or back to the product that is being viewed.

Comment: Further, if you do bring the user to the original page, it would be a good idea to indicate to the user with a message that the person has successfully logged in. Not sure how new you are to ASP or programming in general but validate the hell out of the info that you are being passed from the form page.